# No files being returned files using ../

Tags: html, http, url, path, src

I'm trying to locate a stylesheet, .js file and some images using ../ but it doesn't find anything. I'm using Node.js.
Here is my code:

```
<script src="../public/assets/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/assets/css/styles.css" />
```

and here is my file directory: 
https://monosnap.com/file/dtEK8wLDtVEIQbwC2fqNhWsK1QImR3

I can send the entire .ejs file if it is use to you in solving this problem.

Comment: at what directory is the script located that has this snippet in it? Can you give an overview of your directory structure?

Comment: @DJanssens just updated the question w/ a photo of the file directory.

Comment: And where is the file located that contains this snippet (just to make sure)? In the views folder?

Comment: @DJanssens It's located in views/draw.ejs

Comment: That's rather odd, the locations seem correct. Perhaps already add `type="text/css"`to your link element. But this won't solve your issue. Perhaps check the errors/warnings/logs in your browser window under develop->web inspector->console. Can you access the path by using the console from that directory?

Comment: @DJanssens This is what I get in the console: https://monosnap.com/file/4Yw8yvGpi2llQiCEliQDJ1j1huzmrq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to put this in the app.js:

```
app.use('/socket.io', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io'));
```

"/socket.io" is what you'd put in the src tag in the HTML:

```
src="socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

and this is where the file actually is:

```
__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io'
```

Change the bit in the ''.